# hardware infrastructure for public web application

Tags: hardware-infrastructure

I'd like to start a free budget/personal finance site and will need plenty of horsepower and storage.  I'm definitely a nubee, so how does one get started in terms of hardware infrastructure?  Do I need to get a dedicated IP from my ISP and obtain my own servers?  Do I go with amazon or Sql Server Data Services/Azure or something like that?  Is the latter services free or a discount offering available to non-profit/free services such as the budget/personal finance site I'm looking to start?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind writing your web application in python, then I's suggest using [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/). See: [What Is Google App Engine?](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html)

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do when I have new ideas for a site is to find an inexpensive hosting solution ($10 per month).  This allows me to test the idea and see if the site is going to be successful.  If it is a flop, I haven't wasted much money and if it is successful I can upgrade to better hosting (dedicated server).

There are many hosting options available and several of them have great tools such as an online SQL Server management studio.  Your other option would be to host it yourself if you are prepared to deal with firewall issues, backups, storage, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is feasible to DIY varies a lot by country...if you have a decent broadband connection with a fixed IP this can be the cheapest route to play around with first, especially if you need an awful lot of storage.

Note however that many fast broadband connections are only fast for downloads - when you're running a server, the speed your users will see is the upload speed, which is usually a lot less. Also, you'll need to do your own admin and backup etc.

Apart from this most hosting options have a price tag on top, varying from virtual hosts (sharing a real machine), to colocation (your machine in somebody's data center), to cloud services like amazon et al (which have a good scaling ability)- and you will need to shop around for the software stack and hardware features you really need.

Answer (score 0):

There's really two ways to answer this question, what differentiates them is budget.

One is to properly design this solution, prototype it, benchmark the prototype, extrapolate anticipated user load, add overhead and scale accordingly. This takes time, costs but gives you a supportable solution that serves your customers well.

The other is to just give something, anything a go and fix the problems as they come along. This is quicker and cheaper but might be a headache for a while and might p*** off your customers.

Basically it comes down to budget.

Best of luck.